# Integrating new Web Service code with existing code

Tags: java, web-services, integration

I have an Java Web Application for which we build an EAR and deploy in Websphere 6.
For the first time we are trying to consume a Web Service. (We only need to consume the Web Service, the WSDL path and the WSDL is shared with us)
I have tested the Web Service by using the WSDL provided and getting the clients generated with Eclipse.

I need to know how do I integrate this independent module into my existing, thus everything will go as a single EAR (the existing code + this new clients for the WebService)

Do I need to keep the WSDL as the part of my code as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL would generally be bundled in your application. For a container-managed web service client in a WAR you might:

- place the WSDL and and dependent schemas under WEB-INF
- add a *service-ref* element to the *web.xml*
- load the client code using a JNDI [InitialContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) and the *service-ref-name*

There are some examples in [this IBM jax-ws documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxwsclientdd.html).

On current Java EE versions you might make more use of annotations. It depends on the platform you're targeting and what versions of the web service APIs it supports. I would start with the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxws001.htm).